# Nodejs : RegExp returns nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, parsing

I'm trying to extract the names of electrodes and their values from the Emotiv output. However the code below returns nothing.

I'm a newbie in nodejs. I tried doing it on a single line with Regex but it's too complicated i couldn't get it right. I've succeeded in grabbing the whole line but not the values.

Here is my code :

```
var str = '"levels":{"F3":7094,"FC6":8209,"P7":12165,"T8":5380,"F7":1356,"F8":2043,"T7":11882,"P8":10117,"AF4":13257,"F4":6134,"AF3":13527,"O2":9686,"O1":871,"FC5":1808},"' ; 
    const reg = new RegExp('.{2}\w\"\:\d{3,5}/g'); 
    var test = str.match(reg) ; 
    if (test)   
       console.log(test[1]) ;
```

I expect an output to be  `F3 : 8209` and so on for the 14 electrodes.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: Can you explain the logic, isnt' it: `FC6 : 8209`? And that looks almost like a JSON, so you probably want to use `JSON.parse` instead of a regex.

Comment: He doesn't even need JSON.parse(). Just replace the single quotes with curly braces and you've got an object.
`var data = {"levels":{"F3":7094,"FC6":8209,"P7":12165,"T8":5380,"F7":1356,"F8":2043,"T7":11882,"P8":10117,"AF4":13257,"F4":6134,"AF3":13527,"O2":9686,"O1":871,"FC5":1808}"}`

Comment: It's my bad i copied the wrong value i mean F3 : 7094. I just started using nodejs so i'm a bit confused. 1the real work is extracting the values from my Emotiv output and storing them in a Database. I'm stuck in grabbing them from the output .

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly answering the RegExp question but this rewrite should take get you working faster.

```js
const text = '"levels":{"F3":7094,"FC6":8209,"P7":12165,"T8":5380,"F7":1356,"F8":2043,"T7":11882,"P8":10117,"AF4":13257,"F4":6134,"AF3":13527,"O2":9686,"O1":871,"FC5":1808},"';

let json = "{" + text.substring(0, text.length - 2) + "}"
let obj = JSON.parse(json)

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj.levels)) {
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`); 
}
```

I've also come up with a new RegExp that I think will give you what you want.

```js
const text = '"levels":{"F3":7094,"FC6":8209,"P7":12165,"T8":5380,"F7":1356,"F8":2043,"T7":11882,"P8":10117,"AF4":13257,"F4":6134,"AF3":13527,"O2":9686,"O1":871,"FC5":1808},"';

let regexp = /\"([^\"]{2,3})\"\:(\d{3,5})/g
let r = null
do {
    r = regexp.exec(text)
    if (r) console.log(`${r[1]} ${r[2]}`); 
} while (r)
```